# What does talent placement mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean giving talented people appropriate jobs/positions?
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/placement?q=placement+

She also created a non-profit initiative alongside her fund, Ingressive for Good, which provides micro-scholarships, technical skills development and talent placement for young people in Africa.

Source:https://www.cnbc.com/2021/05/21/how-maya-horgan-famodu-overcame-rejection-at-the-start-of-her-career.html

Comment: Google ["**talent placement**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22talent+placement%22&oq=%22talent+placement%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3387955j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if you need reassurance that your understanding is correct. See also **talent acquisition** - looking at the recruitment agency process from the perspective of the hiring companies, rather than the would-be valued workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Human Resources lingo for *finding jobs for people*. The idea is that people are the *talent* and so she is finding jobs for the talent to be utilized.